# Mixing C/C++ using macros and C style strings

Tags: c++, c

```
gcc/g++ 4.7.2
CXXFLAGS -Wall -Wextra -g -O2
```

Hello,

I have this header file (mu_test.h) that is written using C style. It contain the following marcos

```
#define GET_ERROR() ((errno == 0) ? "None" : strerror(errno))

#define LOG_ERR(fmt, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] %s:%d: errno: %s " fmt "\n", __func__, __LINE__, GET_ERROR(), ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define MU_ASSERT(test, msg) do {               \
        if(!(test)) {                           \
            LOG_ERR(msg);                       \
            return msg;                         \
        }                                       \
    } while(0)
```

I have a cpp file (floor_plan_src.cpp) compiled using g++ that includes the mu_test.h

```
#include "mu_test.h"
char* test_memory_allocation()
{
    plan = new floor_plan();

    MU_ASSERT(plan != NULL, "Failed to allocate memory for floor_plan");

    return NULL;
}
```

I get this warning:

```
deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

So my string constant that I am passing to that function-like marco doesn't like it (C strings) as I have compiled my source using g++.

I thought this problem was to do with mixing c/c++.

solution 1: wrap all the macros in the mu_test.h with extern "C"

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif /* _cplusplus */
#define GET_ERROR() ((errno == 0) ? "None" : strerror(errno))

#define LOG_ERR(fmt, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] %s:%d: errno: %s " fmt "\n", __func__, __LINE__, GET_ERROR(), ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define MU_ASSERT(test, msg) do {               \
        if(!(test)) {                           \
            LOG_ERR(msg);                       \
            return msg;                         \
        }                                       \
    } while(0)
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

Solution 1 still gave me the same warning.

solution 2: wrap the header file in floor_plan_src.cpp

```
extern "C" {
#include "mu_test.h"
}
```

Solution 2 still gave me the same warning

Solution 3: wrap the function

```
extern "C" char* test_memory_allocation()
{
    plan = new floor_plan();

    MU_ASSERT(plan != NULL, "Failed to allocate memory for floor_plan");

    return NULL;
}
```

Solution 3 same as above

Solution 4:
Try and convert the constant string to a non-const char*

```
MU_ASSERT(plan != NULL, (char*)"Failed to allocate memory for floor_plan");
```

gave the following error:

```
 expected primary-expression before char
"[ERROR] %s:%d: errno: %s " cannot be used as a function
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: do you need the `##` in `##__VA_ARGS__`

Comment: That is needed to avoid the trailing comma i.e this would not work without it. LOG_ERR("ERROR HAPPENED"); As I am not passing any arguments.

Comment: Your use of `LOG_ERR` is a bit dangerous in `MU_ASSERT`, it will crash and burn if `msg` accidentally contains format specifiers. You should probably call it like this: `LOG_ERR("%s", msg);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `test_memory_allocation` might return a string literal, and you shouldn't make a string literal decay to non-const `char*`: it's allowed in C++, but still deprecated.

Your code gets expanded in:

```
char* test_memory_allocation()
{
    plan = new floor_plan();

    do {
        if(!(plan != NULL)) {
            LOG_ERR("Failed to allocate memory for floor_plan")
            return "Failed to allocate memory for floor_plan";
        }
    } while(0);

    return NULL;
}
```

To fix it you just need to make `test_memory_allocation` return a `const char*` or otherwise you could return a pointer to something that could decay to a non-const `char*` (for example a static `char` array or to a heap-allocated memory area).

`extern "C"` is only needed to avoid C++ name mangling, it only affects functions, not macros.

Comment: Hello Peoro. So using the extern "C" in this case is pointless then? I solved the problem by casting to a (char*) #define MU_ASSERT(test, msg) do {               \
        if(!(test)) {                           \
            LOG_ERR(msg);                       \
            return (char*)msg;                  \
        }                                       \
    } while(0)

Comment: @ant2009: It's pointless insofar as a) it does not change the language (only the linkage) and b) it's undefined behaviour in C as well.

Comment: @ant2009 Instead of casting `const char*` to `char*`, you should change return type of `test_memory_allocation()` to be `const char*`. That is, if you can do it. If it's part of fixed API, then you can't...